# Install Update/Beta Update of an app on Managed Device

Tags: android, google-play, android-for-work, android-management-api

I am not able to find an api equivalent to 
`Installs: update` of Google Play EMM API [here](https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/v1/installs/update) in Android Management API.

Can anyone please help with the API or any policy that can be used to install an update to a fully managed device. There is a concept of `policy.productAvailabilityPolicy to push beta updates of an app` in Devices in Play EMM API, it's also missing in Android Management API.

Comment: did you ever resolve this? [I'm having issues deploying alpha track updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55159641/using-android-management-api-devices-enrolled-to-an-organisation-cant-utilis) to my devices via private policy + organisations. If I can push updates to specific devices directly via the android management API that would be a lot more graceful