# How to distribute private Android app testing tracks using the Android Management API + Organisations?

Tags: android, google-play, android-testing, android-management-api, android-enterprise

So I'm using the Android Management API to manage and handle deployment for an app to a kiosk device I am working on.

I've created an organisation, created a policy, and ensured the app is limited to managed google play only, and assigned the organisation to the app.

I've enrolled some devices onto the policy, and when the app is moved to prod (currently this is fine as there are only a handful of test devices on that policy), it downloads and installs.

However my issue is that if I use the alpha track, and then assign the organisation to that alpha track, the new alpha version of the app never gets installed.

[image: android alpha track]

Using the opt-in URL (not ideal, as the policy doesn't have Chrome on it, so I would need to specifically add chrome just for alpha testing), then sign into google with an account on that organisation. It then tells me I am enrolled into alpha, and it may take a few hours for the app to show up.

[image]

[The google docs on this are extremely vague](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en-GB)

> If your app is private, you also need to add the organisation
>   associated with your test to your targeted list.

Like 16 hours later, no app, only the prod version which comes pre installed. If I call that device from the Android Management API, and show installed apps, it shows only the prod / previous version of the app.

**So my question:** How do I get the app onto the device via the alpha test channel, while using a private app + organisation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2019-09-09**

The Android Management API now supports distributing testing tracks:

- You can find the list of available tracks for an app with [Application.appTracks[]](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.applications)
- You can set the available tracks for a policy in [ApplicationPolicy.accessibleTrackIds[]](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#ApplicationPolicy)

---

**Initial answer 2019-03-14**

The Android Management API doesn't support distributing testing tracks at the moment. We are working on adding support for it, however I cannot share a precise timeline at the moment.

Once support is added you will be able to set a field in the `ApplicationPolicy` to distribute testing track of an app to a device. Similar to how it is currently possible using the Play EMM API (see [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/distribute#distribute_closed_tracks_to_users)).

Unfortunately there is no workaround. Using the opt-in URL from the device would not work with the Android Management API. And you cannot use the Play EMM API for devices managed with the Android Management API.

Comment: Thats a shame, although thanks for weighing in. Would it not make sense to amend the docs to reflect this information? As I've lost a couple of days trying to do something I had presumed was possible. So really the only way to handle this currently is to deploy directly to prod? Also how can I be notified when this is possible?

Comment: Currently it's only possible to distribute prod version of apps indeed. Once support for testing tracks is available we will announce it on the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/android/management/release-notes) and I will make sure to update this StackOverflow question as well. And thank for the feedback about the documentation, we will look into it.

Comment: Is there any news on if / when this is happening yet? Its becoming pretty dangerous just having to distribute new features without a proper testing process

Comment: We plan to release support for testing tracks in the Android Management API in August.

Comment: The Android Management API supports testing tracks. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Fred When I call this method GET https://androidmanagement.googleapis.com/v1/{name=enterprises/*/applications/*} I don't get any AppTrackInfo objects. And I have multiple tracks at the moment including open beta, closed alpha and production. Must my app be a Managed Google play app to allow for this functionality?

Comment: I actually have a Managed Google Play app and don't see my app tracks being recognized.  So I am having the same issue as @Johan . My comment from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63714071/how-do-accessible-track-ids-get-applied-to-app-using-android-management-api) :   I have an app on the production track and did a build last night to open testing (beta). It is 1.0.19, while the production is 1.0.18. I did a policy and added the accessibleTrackId for the beta. Just deployed it, but the app info still says 1.0.18 (the production one).