# Android Kiosk mode not working when using Android Management API Policy

Tags: android, kiosk, device-admin, cosu, android-management-api

So I'm trying to get a single use, dedicated app + device to work in kiosk mode + auto launch. The app itself is built in Nativescript (with Angular), so not native Java, however this is still handled via an admin receiver etc as normal.

When we use `adb` to set the device owner, kiosk mode works as expected.

```
adb shell dpm set-device-owner com.domain.app/.DeviceAdminReceiver
```

When we use an Android Management policy to enrol the device and auto install, the kiosk mode is never initiated correctly.

```
{
  "name": "enterprises/LC00mpaqaj/policies/policy1",
  "version": "12",
  "applications": [
    {
      "packageName": "com.domain.app",
      "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
      "lockTaskAllowed": true,
      "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    }
  ],
  "persistentPreferredActivities": [
    {
      "receiverActivity": "com.domain.app/.DeviceAdminReceiver",
      "actions": [
        "android.intent.action.MAIN"
      ],
      "categories": [
        "android.intent.category.HOME",
        "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "dataRoamingDisabled": true,
  "kioskCustomLauncherEnabled": true
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml - the part relevant to the admin receiver

```
<receiver
    android:name=".DeviceAdminReceiver"
    android:lockTaskMode="if_whitelisted"
    android:description="@string/admin_description"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.device_admin"
        android:resource="@xml/admin_permissions" />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

When I do a GET on the individual device via the AMAPI it shows..

```
{
  "name": "enterprises/LC00mpaqaj/devices/3e26eac6be79d049",
  "managementMode": "DEVICE_OWNER",
  "state": "ACTIVE",
  "appliedState": "ACTIVE",
  "policyCompliant": true,
  "nonComplianceDetails": [
    {
      "settingName": "persistentPreferredActivities",
      "nonComplianceReason": "INVALID_VALUE",
      "packageName": "com.domain.app"
    }
  ],...
```

So it seems to not be liking the `persistentPreferredActivities`, however I have been playing around trying examples I have found both on this [medium kiosk article](https://medium.com/ackee/dedicated-one-app-device-with-android-management-api-39cf498f8c9b), as well as the actual [google kiosk policy examples](https://developers.google.com/android/management/policies/dedicated-devices).

Based on those examples I have tried using various `receiverActivity` alternative formats, and still no joy:

```
"receiverActivity": "com.domain.app/.DeviceAdminReceiver",
"receiverActivity": "com.domain.app",
"receiverActivity": "com.domain.app/.com.domain.app.DeviceAdminReceiver",
```

**So my question:** Why can I not get android kiosk mode to work with my policy, but it works fine with ADB?

Semi related, [I can't use google play test tracks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55159641/how-to-distribute-private-android-app-testing-tracks-using-the-android-managemen/55166866#55166866) in testing my possible resolutions, so I am having to push changes to prod track, which makes my development cycle fairly long / arduous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not an Android Management API expert, but did you try without the `kioskCustomLauncherEnabled` parameter? In the test I've run with it, it launches Google's own Kiosk app, maybe preventing your activity to launch.

My two cents :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd just like to add that you no longer need `persistentPreferredActivities` or `lockType` if you set `"installType": "KIOSK"`.

This seems to be a new feature that's been introduced this year and I've just found out about it (nothing in the changelog). It should simplify your config somewhat.